# Trouble with Stored Procedure Average function

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure that is taking data from two different tables and averages the metrics based on week.  The data from one table looks fine.  However, the other is just the same values repeated for all weeks.  I have checked the source table multiple times and averaged the data myself and the numbers should all be different.

Here is the stored proc in question.

```
INSERT INTO Metrics
(
    Application,
    App1_Performance,
    App1_Availability,
    App2_Performance,
    App2_Availability,
    week,
    Current_Week
)

SELECT 
    COALESCE (k.Application, n.Application) AS App,
    AVG(k.Performance) AS App1_Perf,
    AVG(k.Availability) AS App1_Avail,
    AVG(n.Performance) AS App2_Perf,
    AVG(n.Availability) AS App2_Avail,
    COALESCE (DATEPART(wk, n.Timestamp), DATEPART(wk, k.Timestamp)) AS inputweek,
    DATEPART(wk, GETDATE()) AS currentweek
FROM Table1App1 k
FULL OUTER JOIN Table2App2 n
on k.Application = n.Application    
GROUP BY COALESCE (k.Application, n.Application), COALESCE (DATEPART(wk, n.Timestamp), DATEPART(wk, k.Timestamp))
```

My results look like this

```
App    App1_Perf    App1_Avail  App2_Perf   App2_Avail  inputweek   currentweek
Site    0.740778    99.988252   0.154594    100.000000  50  51
Site    0.740778    99.988252   1.852053    100.000000  49  51
Site    0.740778    99.988252   0.200000    100.000000  46  51
Site    0.740778    99.988252   0.140000    100.000000  47  51
Site    0.740778    99.988252   0.143376    100.000000  48  51
Site    0.740778    99.988252   0.151363    100.000000  51  51
```

The data for App2 looks good but App1 just repeats the same values.  Can anyone see anything I am doing wrong in the stored proc that would cause this?

Comment: print the result of the query without Agreggated function or GROUP BY and  you will see what is wrong.

Comment: If I am remembering the time I had a similar problem correctly, I know the answer. It is subtle, but you need an additional JOIN between DATEPART(wk, n.Timestamp) and DATEPART(wk, k.Timestamp)

Comment: I removed the Aggregation and Group BY and the value is the current week value.  That explains what the value is that is showing up for App1 but why not for App2?

Comment: @Laughing Vergil - In the select statement?

Comment: What is happening without the JOIN on the week is that there is nothing ensuring that the weeks being summarized are the same in both tables. So, since the 'n' table is being coalesced first, it will be limited to that week, but the 'k' table will be processing all of the rows matched by Application. If you reversed the two tables in the COALESCE, then the k table would vary, and the n table would all be the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your FULL OUTER JOIN to include the week information in the join, and you should get rid of that issue.

```
INSERT INTO Metrics
(
    Application,
    App1_Performance,
    App1_Availability,
    App2_Performance,
    App2_Availability,
    week,
    Current_Week
)

SELECT 
    COALESCE (k.Application, n.Application) AS App,
    AVG(k.Performance) AS App1_Perf,
    AVG(k.Availability) AS App1_Avail,
    AVG(n.Performance) AS App2_Perf,
    AVG(n.Availability) AS App2_Avail,
    COALESCE (DATEPART(wk, n.Timestamp), DATEPART(wk, k.Timestamp)) AS inputweek,
    DATEPART(wk, GETDATE()) AS currentweek
FROM Table1App1 k
FULL OUTER JOIN Table2App2 n
    on k.Application = n.Application
    AND DATEPART(wk, n.Timestamp) = DATEPART(wk, k.Timestamp) 
GROUP BY COALESCE (k.Application, n.Application), COALESCE (DATEPART(wk, n.Timestamp), DATEPART(wk, k.Timestamp))
```